# Django timeout before submitting background task

Tags: django, heroku, celery

I maintain a Django app hosted on Heroku. We use DRF intensively to serve our FE app.

Django version: 2.2.21.
Celery version: 4.2.2

We have an endpoint that works perfectly well 99% of the time, but sometimes, it timeouts.

We use Sentry to monitor and you can find the traces [here](https://sentry.io/share/issue/791a44ef15404e36a1f52332b4217a90/).

FYI but maybe it is not useful, this endpoint:

- Has very little processing then starts a background task.
- In the breadcrumb of Sentry, we can see that the REDIS LPUSH command is triggered at the very end of the 20s heroku timeout.
- It is happening only in production and not staging and we cannot reproduce it

It seems to me that the function calls is going back and forth between

```
django/core/handlers/exception.py in inner at line 34
django/utils/deprecation.py in __call__ at line 94
```

This has been happening for months now and we still do not have a solution.

Any idea as to why this might happen?
And why only in certain cases?

Thank you very much for the help!

Robin Bonnin

Comment: Those 2 lines from the traceback you've mentioned is nothing suspicious - it is just a code used in middlewares to convert the old style middleware to the new style. It is called several times, because you have this amount of middlewares using it.

Comment: Are you performing any atomic transactions and then starting the background task.

Comment: @RanjanMP We are not performing any atomic transaction. Only very basic python to parse the body of the request.

Thank you for your response. Good to know